# Могу ли я передать в функцию несколько аргументов в виде массива

Tags: python, функции

```
def a(*args):
    return np.random.randint(args)
```

Я хочу передать всю сигнатуру функции a в нижнюю функцию

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте:

```
def a(*args):
    return np.random.randint(*args)

print(a(1, 2))
```

---

- `def a(*args):` - в функции `args` это указание на неопределенное количество аргументов, например при `a(1, 2, "a")` в `args` будет `[1, 2, "a"]`
- `np.random.randint(*args)` - звездочка в `*args` это распаковка списка по аргументам в функцию. Это `np.random.randint(*[1, 2])` тоже самое что `np.random.randint(1, 2)`